# Include matched part in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

My try:

```
$a = preg_split("/[0-9](\-)[0-9]/", $d);
print_r($a);
```

If `$d=sometext9-9sometext`, I want to be able to get from `print_r($a);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => sometext9
    [1] => -
    [2] => 9sometext
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't need to escape hyphen, except inside `[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
$re = "/(?<=[0-9])(-)(?=[0-9])/"; 
$str = "sometext9-9sometext"; 
$a = preg_split($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($a);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Hxy7Jy). Since the `-` is in Group 1 (enclosed with `(...)`) and we use [`PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), the hyphen is returned as part of the resulting array.

> `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`
>   If this flag is set, *parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well*.

The **[lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** `(?<=[0-9])` and `(?=[0-9])` check for but do not consume the digits on both ends thus they are kept in the elements adjoining to `-`. See more on that behavior at [*Lookarounds Stand their Ground*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground).

Comment: You forgot the demo link =D  (disregard you still working on it)